# To create a walkthrough page that appears only when the application is installed

Tags: android, installation, walkthrough

I'm developing an mobile where the walkthrough page about the application should appear only once the application is installed. Can anyone help me resolving this issue with a clear example.

Comment: Hold a `boolean indicator` initially as `false`in `SharedPreferences` then in application opening show walkthrough if that is `false` and change it to `true` to not run your walkthorugh `function` again

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your method:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

// Default value returned by next line is true.
boolean firstLaunch = prefs.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true);
if (firstLaunch) {
  // Do whatever you want here. This will be called only the first time the app launches.

  // Then edit the SharedPreferences and put the value as false. Unless changed back to true, this if statement/loop will never be called again.
  prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstLaunch", false).apply();
}
```

Note: `PREFERENCES_NAME` is just a String. It can be anything. I suggest you use the same `PREFERENCES_NAME` in all of your app, in case you need to access SharedPreferences somewhere else.